# CNN image extraction to predict a continuous value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have images of vehicles . I need to predict the price of the vehicle based on image extraction. 
What I have learnt is , I can use CNN to extract the image features but what I am not able to get is, How to predict the prices of vehicles. 
I know that the I need to train my CNN model before it predicts the price. 
I don't know how to train the model with **images along with prices** .

In the end what I expect is , I will input an vehicle image and I need to get price of the vehicle.

Can any one provide the approach for this ?

Comment: how would you train a neural net to solve any other regression problem? That is to say, given a set of input features X, predict an output y. Can you train a NN to predict house prices using the boston dataset? This problem is no different from that

Comment: Yes , but here input is an image not the numerical values..

Comment: that doesn't change anything. to a computer an image is just a series of numerical values, afterall

Answer (score -1):

I would use the CNN to predict the model of the car and then using a list of all the car prices it's easy enough to get the price, or if you dont care about the car model just use the prices as lables